# SQL divide by zero error nullif not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an equation

```
( ( P.RealisedConsumption / ( NULLIF(( PO.ActualQty * P.QuantityPO ), 0) / 1000000 ) ) - 1 ) * 100 AS FibreScrapFactor
```

This works for the example order that I am looking at.  However if i take out the where clause (so i have all orders) i get divide by zero error.

If I limit the / 1000000 to 10 which i then have

```
( ( P.RealisedConsumption / ( NULLIF(( PO.ActualQty * P.QuantityPO ), 0) / 10 ) ) - 1 ) * 100 AS FibreScrapFactor
```

This works for all orders, but is incorrect I need to divide by a million.  How can I get this to work? Thanks!

This also gives me divide by zero error

```
( ( P.RealisedConsumption / ( ( NULLIF(PO.ActualQty, 0) * NULLIF(P.QuantityPO, 0) ) / 1000000 ) ) - 1 ) * 100 AS FibreScrapFactor
```

Comment: Why would dividing by 1 million throw a divide by 0 error?  Why are you checking if `10` is null?

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, you need a `CASE` statement to swap out `0` for whatever value you are trying to substitute.  Or put a predicate in the `WHERE` clause to skip rows where certain columns are `null`.

Comment: I don't know... i just read that if you get this use null if on what your dividing by... this is part of  amuch bigger query i can't skip rows where there are null columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CASE WHEN (PO.ActualQty * P.QuantityPO / 1000000) <> 0 THEN
    ( P.RealisedConsumption / ( PO.ActualQty * P.QuantityPO / 1000000 ) - 1 ) * 100 
END AS FibreScrapFactor
```

Comment: This works!!! Thank you! I don't see how this is different than using null if's though?

Comment: You could have used `NULLIF`, but then you should put the whole expression: `NULLIF( (PO.ActualQty * P.QuantityPO / 1000000), 0)`. But I think the `CASE` notation is easier to understand.

Comment: Check out Giorgi Nakeuri's answer, he has a point you want to address too.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is because of types. You have nested devision operations and if the type of columns are `int` and the values get less then `1000000` then you are getting `0` as a result of inner operation. When you change to `10` obviously you just don't get `0` since multiplication result is greater then `10` in inner operation:

This will throw an error:

```
select 2 / (1 / 10)
```

Workaround is just to multiply inner result to `1.0` to make result of numeric type:

```
select 2 / (1 * 1.0 / 10)
```

Comment: Hi Giorgi, long time no speak... the datatypes are all numeric(32,16)